# How to write an SPA in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, clang

I wonder if it is possible? I am working on a windows machine and using LLVM as compiler. I want to use C++ as my back-end without writing a separate service.

Comment: What is an SPA?  Single Page Application?

Comment: You really need to explain a bit more about what you are trying to do. LLVM can be used to do a lot of things, but without explaining further, I doubt you will get much of an answer.